# How can I change the label's text, when I click to the button in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Label called "something" and a button called "a". 
When I click the buttton the label have to show "You pressed the button".
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `Click` event to your button:

```
<Button Name="a" Click="ChangeLabelClick" Content="Change Label" />
```

Your label:

```
<Label Name="something" Content="" />
```

And here is event itself:

```
private void ChangeLabelClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    something.Content = "You pressed the button";
}
```

Comment: just a quick note, the function called when the button is clicked should be called something like `button_Click` to denote, which event called this function and not their purpose (changing the label name). This will follow the microsoft naming standards under https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members?redirectedfrom=MSDN and follow their lead of auto generated code for event methods. Additional to that, the method does not have to be async (and VS e.g. will show an error here) because it does not contain any await functionalities